# How to display an uploaded image manipulated with PIL without saving to file Django

Tags: python, django

I am pulling a image from a database to be used as a background and placing a user uploaded image on top of the background using PIL. I would like to display this image to the html page after the transformation is complete without saving to the file system. I have looked at many similar questions, but I am doing something different here. I have tried to craft some code based on the other answers, but I can't get the image to display on the screen after the user submits their photo. How can I get this to work? Here is my code:

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import base64
import io
from .models import Samplecards

def imageUpload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        selection = request.POST['selection']
        sample = getImage()
        theImage = io.BytesIO(sample.image)
        print("DONE")

        uploaded_image = request.FILES['img']

        foreground = Image.open(uploaded_image).convert("RGBA")
        background = Image.open(theImage).convert("RGBA")

        background.paste(foreground, (440, 190), foreground)
        buffered = BytesIO()
        background.save(buffered, format="png")
        b64_img = base64.b64encode(buffered.getvalue())

    return render(request, 'uploadpage.html', {"image": b64_img})

def getImage():
    img = Samplecards.objects.get(image_id=1)
    return img
```

In my html file, I try to display the image like this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{image}}">
```

Comment: What is displayed and what do you see in your HTML? No errors in your django console?

Comment: I see the standard broken image link on the screen. I see NameError: name 'BytesIO' is not defined in the console.

Comment: And what do you see in the rendered HTML?

Comment: I just get the broken image icon on the screen.

Comment: I mean the HTML! look at your source

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean. Are you asking what is rendered on the screen?

Comment: No i'm asking what is the source HTML. The first thing you should **always** do when you don't see an expected result in a template is open up the HTML source in your browser developer tools and look at how your template was rendered to HTML.

Comment: Oh ok I see. So I changed buffered = BytesIO() to buffered = io.BytesIO(). That seemed to fix the console error. In the html source I see an extremely long string of letters and numbers where I am trying to display the image.

Comment: That would indicate that your code works. Maybe try marking `image` as `safe` (`{{ image|safe }}`) or disabling `autoescape` around the `<img>` tag, not sure if that could help.

Comment: Or try comparing the string sent by django to the template (print `b64_img` or set a breakpoint) with the string you see in the HTML.

Comment: Still no luck. However, I appreciate the help.